# Running distributed Tensorflow with InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: tensorflow

I have implemented a variational autoencoder with tensorflow on a single machine. Now I am trying to run it on my cluster with the distributed mechanism provided tensorflow. But the following problem had stuck me for several days.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yama/mfs/ZhuSuan/examples/vae.py", line 265, in <module>
    print('>> Test log likelihood = {}'.format(np.mean(test_lls)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 942, in managed_session
    self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 768, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 322, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 267, in stop_on_exception
    yield
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 411, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 972, in run_loop
    self._sv.global_step])
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: model_1/fully_connected_10/Relu_G88 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=3964479821165574552, tensor_name="edge_694_model_1/fully_connected_10/Relu", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/home/yama/mfs/ZhuSuan/examples/vae.py", line 201, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, x_train.shape[1]))
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 895, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1238, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/mfs/yama/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Here is my code, I just paste the main function for simplicity:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.set_random_seed(1234)

    # Load MNIST
    data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                             'data', 'mnist.pkl.gz')
    x_train, t_train, x_valid, t_valid, x_test, t_test = \
        dataset.load_mnist_realval(data_path)
    x_train = np.vstack([x_train, x_valid])
    np.random.seed(1234)
    x_test = np.random.binomial(1, x_test, size=x_test.shape).astype('float32')

    # Define hyper-parametere
    n_z = 40

    # Define training/evaluation parameters
    lb_samples = 1
    ll_samples = 5000
    epoches = 10
    batch_size = 100
    test_batch_size = 100
    iters = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size
    test_iters = x_test.shape[0] // test_batch_size
    test_freq = 10

    ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
    worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

    # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
    clusterSpec = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

    print("Create and start a server for the local task.")
    # Create and start a server for the local task.
    server = tf.train.Server(clusterSpec,
                             job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                             task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

    print("Start ps and worker server")
    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
        server.join()
    elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
        #set distributed device
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
            worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
            cluster=clusterSpec)):

            print("Build the training computation graph")
            # Build the training computation graph
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, x_train.shape[1]))
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, epsilon=1e-4)
            with tf.variable_scope("model") as scope:
                with pt.defaults_scope(phase=pt.Phase.train):
                    train_model = M1(n_z, x_train.shape[1])
                    train_vz_mean, train_vz_logstd = q_net(x, n_z)
                    train_variational = ReparameterizedNormal(
                        train_vz_mean, train_vz_logstd)
                    grads, lower_bound = advi(
                        train_model, x, train_variational, lb_samples, optimizer)
                    infer = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads)

            print("Build the evaluation computation graph")
            # Build the evaluation computation graph
            with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True) as scope:
                with pt.defaults_scope(phase=pt.Phase.test):
                    eval_model = M1(n_z, x_train.shape[1])
                    eval_vz_mean, eval_vz_logstd = q_net(x, n_z)
                    eval_variational = ReparameterizedNormal(
                        eval_vz_mean, eval_vz_logstd)
                    eval_lower_bound = is_loglikelihood(
                        eval_model, x, eval_variational, lb_samples)
                    eval_log_likelihood = is_loglikelihood(
                        eval_model, x, eval_variational, ll_samples)

            global_step = tf.Variable(0)
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
            init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        # Create a "supervisor", which oversees the training process.
        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                 logdir=LogDir,
                                 init_op=init_op,
                                 summary_op=summary_op,
                                 saver=saver,
                                 global_step=global_step,
                                 save_model_secs=600)
        # Run the inference
        with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
            epoch = 0
            while not sv.should_stop() and epoch < epoches:
            #for epoch in range(1, epoches + 1):
                np.random.shuffle(x_train)
                lbs = []
                for t in range(iters):
                    x_batch = x_train[t * batch_size:(t + 1) * batch_size]
                    x_batch = np.random.binomial( n=1, p=x_batch, size=x_batch.shape).astype('float32')
                    _, lb = sess.run([infer, lower_bound], feed_dict={x: x_batch})
                    lbs.append(lb)
                if epoch % test_freq == 0:
                    test_lbs = []
                    test_lls = []
                    for t in range(test_iters):
                        test_x_batch = x_test[
                            t * test_batch_size: (t + 1) * test_batch_size]
                        test_lb, test_ll = sess.run(
                            [eval_lower_bound, eval_log_likelihood],
                            feed_dict={x: test_x_batch}
                        )
                        test_lbs.append(test_lb)
                        test_lls.append(test_ll)
                    print('>> Test lower bound = {}'.format(np.mean(test_lbs)))
                    print('>> Test log likelihood = {}'.format(np.mean(test_lls)))
        sv.stop()
```

I have try to correct my code for several days, but all my efforts have failed. Looking for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The most likely cause of this exception is that one of the operations that the [`tf.train.Supervisor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Supervisor) runs in the background depends on the [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) tensor `x`, but doesn't have enough information to feed a value for it.

The most likely culprit is `summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()`, because library code often summarizes values that depend on the training data. To prevent the supervisor from collecting summaries in the background, pass `summary_op=None` to the `tf.train.Supervisor` constructor:

```
        # Create a "supervisor", which oversees the training process.
        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                 logdir=LogDir,
                                 init_op=init_op,
                                 summary_op=None,
                                 saver=saver,
                                 global_step=global_step,
                                 save_model_secs=600)
```

After doing this, you will need to make alternative arrangements to collect summaries. The easiest way to do this is to pass `summary_op` to `sess.run()` periodically, then pass the result to [`sv.summary_computed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Supervisor.summary_computed).

Comment: Sorry, the last comments is not complete. I tried your solution, the error remains. If the program invokes sess.run(summary_op) and sv.summary_computed(). The error log still reminds me that "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor". Or if I just set summary_op=None without running sess.run(summary_op) periodically, the program will be stuck. Any further advice? Thank you, and looking for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Came across a similar thing. The chief was going down with the aforementioned error message. However, since I was using the MonitoredTrainingSession rather than a self-made Supervisor, I was able to solve the problem by disabling the default summary. To disable, you have to provide

```
save_summaries_secs=None,
save_summaries_steps=None,
```

to the constructor of the MonitoredTrainingSession. Afterwards, everything went just smooth!
[Code on Github](http://github.com/Project-Ellie/capsnet-fashion)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. Following mrry's suggestion I was able to work this out by:

1. Disabling summary logging in the supervisor by setting summary_op=None (as mrry suggested)
2. Creating my own summary_op and pass it to sess.run() along with the rest of the ops to be evaluated. Hold on the resulting summary, let's say it's called 'my_summary'.
3. Creating my own summary writer. Call it with 'my_summary', e.g.: summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch_count)

To clarify, I did not use mrry's suggestion to do
sess.run(summary_op) and sv.summary_computed(), but instead ran the summary_op along with the other operations, and then wrote out the summary myself. You might also want to condition the summary writing on being a chief.

So basically, you need to bypass the Supervisor's summary writing services completely. Seems like surprising limitation/bug of Supervisor since it isn't exactly uncommon to want to log things that depend on the input (which lives in a placeholder). For example in my network (an autoencoder) the cost depends on the input.