# Saving model for Tensorflow Serving while using Tensorflow distributed training

Tags: tensorflow, model, export, distributed, tensorflow-serving

We are planning to implement distributed training in Tensorflow. For that, we are using Tensorflow Distributed (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed). 
We are able to achieve distributed training using "asynchronous between graph replication training". Below is the code snippet.

---

```
.....
ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
# Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

# Create and start a server for the local task.
server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                       job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                       task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
img_width, img_height = 124, 124

if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

####### Assigns ops to the local worker by default.#######
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
    cluster=cluster)):

######## set Keras learning phase to train #######
  K.set_learning_phase(1)
  # do not initialize variables on the fly
  K.manual_variable_initialization(True)

  if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
      input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
  else:
      input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

  X= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, img_width, img_height, 3], name= "X")
  Y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, n_classes], name="Y")

  print("Building keras model")

  ....
  ....

  ####### Defining our total loss ####### 

  ###### Defining our TF Optimizer and passing hyperparameters ######      
  .......
  ...........
  ...............
```

We have defined our training supervisor like as per below.

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                           logdir=logdir,
                           init_op=init_op,
                           saver=saver,
                           summary_op=summary_op,
                           global_step=global_step)
```

We have also initialized the supervisor using below code snippet.

```
with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target) as sess:
```

Then we have passed on different batches during the training. Till this part everything works fine. But when we are trying save/export the model for tensorflow serving, it's not generating right set of check point files so that we can serve it in production. While hosting the checkpoint files through tensorflow_model_server, we are getting below error.

---

```
 Loading servable: {name: default version: 2} failed: Invalid argument: 
 Cannot assign a device for operation 'init_all_tables': Operation was 
 explicitly assigned to /job:worker/task:0 but available devices are [ 
 /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 ]. Make sure the device specification 
 refers to a valid device.[[Node: init_all_tables = 
 NoOp[_device="/job:worker/task:0"]()]]
```

Just to note, we have also tried following methods to save the trained graph.

i) SavedModelBuilder

```
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
```

ii) Model exporter

```
export_path = "/saved_graph/"
model_exporter.export(export_path, sess)
```

iii) tf.train.Saver - function

```
tf.train.Saver
```

- but with above none of the scenarios we have seen success.

We couldn't find any direct article which shows a complete example or explain things in details.We have gone through below reference links.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5439 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5110 
[Running distributed Tensorflow with InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825741/running-distributed-tensorflow-with-invalidargumenterror-you-must-feed-a-value?rq=1)

Any suggestions or reference would be of great help.

Thank you.

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

As per the suggestions, We have tried to use "clear_devices=True" while exporting the model but that didn't help. Below is the code snippet which we have used.

```
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

        epoch_num=0

        batch_count = int(num_img/batch_size)
        count = 0

        for i in range(batch_count):

            epoch_num=0

          # This will create batches out of out Training dataset and it will 
           pe passed to the feed_dict    
            batch_x, batch_y = 
            next_batch(batch_size,epoch_num,train_data,train_labels,num_img)

          # perform the operations we defined earlier on batch
            _, cost, step = sess.run([train_op, cross_entropy, global_step],

            feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(path)
            builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess,
            [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map= {
            "magic_model": 
             tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
             inputs= {"image": X},
             outputs= {"prediction": preds})
             }, clear_devices=True)
            builder.save()

            sv.stop()
            print("Done!!")
```

We are getting below error when we are using clear_devices=True..

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "insulator_classifier.py", line 370, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "insulator_classifier.py", line 283, in main
}, clear_devices=False)
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 364, in 
add_meta_graph_and_variables
allow_empty=True)
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1140, in __init__
self.build()
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1172, in build
filename=self._filename)
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 677, in build
filename_tensor = constant_op.constant(filename or "model")
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 106, in constant
attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2582, in create_op
self._check_not_finalized()
File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2290, in 
_check_not_finalized
raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Anything we are missing in here ??

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

### Further update :

We can see that it works with suggestion 2) from @Tianjin Gu 
Please see below code snippet

```
    X= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, img_width, img_height, 3], name= "X")
    Y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, n_classes], name="Y")

    ....
    ....

    model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
          model_exporter.init(
     tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(),
    named_graph_signatures={
             'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({'input': X}),
             'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({'output': Y})}, clear_devices=True)
          export_path = "/export_path"
```

As we exporter we see this warning -

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:From test_classifier.py:283: Exporter.export (from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle.exporter) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-06-30.
```

So we should ideally use "tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder" - but that's not working for some reason.

Any further suggestion ?

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, what is the remaining error you are experiencing with SavedModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2):

Notice `clear_devices=True`;

1. If use `SavedModelBuilder`, set `clear_devices=True` when calling `add_meta_graph()` or `add_meta_graph_and_variables()`
2. If use `exporter`, set `clear_devices=True` when constructing `exporter.Exporter`

## Update:

1. For use `SavedModelBuilder` issue, it does not need to create a `SavedModelBuilder` every epoch, so your should move the lines before for loop and it does not need save model every epoch either, you can move `builder.save()` after for loop. So the code will be like：

   ```
   builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(path)

   builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                        signature_def_map = {"magic_model": tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(inputs= {"image": X}, outputs= {"prediction": preds})},
                                        clear_devices=True)

   for epoch in range(training_epochs):

       epoch_num=0

       batch_count = int(num_img/batch_size)
       count = 0

       for i in range(batch_count):

           epoch_num=0

         # This will create batches out of out Training dataset and it will pe passed to the feed_dict
           batch_x, batch_y =
           next_batch(batch_size,epoch_num,train_data,train_labels,num_img)

         # perform the operations we defined earlier on batch
           _, cost, step = sess.run([train_op, cross_entropy, global_step],

           feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
           sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

   builder.save()
   sv.stop()
   print("Done!!")
   ```
2. For use `export.Exporter` the warning does not matter too much, you can still load the file by TensorFlowServing

Comment: Thanks @Tianjin Gu. We have tried your suggest but that's throwing below error.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.

Comment: I have edited the questions with more information about the test with "clear_devices=True"

Comment: We have tested the export with suggestion 2) "exporter.Exporter" it works. I have edited the questions for more details. But any suggestions to fix the issue with "tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Tianjin Gu. We would try that out.